# How to get value of corresponding x-axis label on click event of rectangular bars in nvd3.js historical chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have created a historical bar chart using nvd3 js. I want to get the value of corresponding x-axis label when a bar is clicked. How to get value of corresponding x-axis label on click event of rectangular bars in nvd3.js historical chart?

My current code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="../build/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.2/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../build/nv.d3.js"></script>

    <style>
        text {
            font: 12px sans-serif;
        }
        svg {
            display: block;
        }
        html, body, svg {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class='with-3d-shadow with-transitions'>

<svg id="test1"></svg>

<script>

    var chart;
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        chart = nv.models.historicalBarChart();
        chart
            .margin({left: 100, bottom: 100})
            .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
            .duration(250)
            ;

        // chart sub-models (ie. xAxis, yAxis, etc) when accessed directly, return themselves, not the parent chart, so need to chain separately
        chart.xAxis
            .axisLabel("Time (s)")
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

        chart.yAxis
            .axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

        chart.showXAxis(true);

        d3.select('#test1')
            .datum(sinData())
            .transition()
            .call(chart);

            var rectArray=d3.select('g.nv-bars').selectAll('rect').on('click',function(d,i){alert(d+i)});

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });

    //Simple test data generators
    function sinAndCos() {
        var sin = [],
            cos = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            sin.push({x: i*2, y: Math.sin(i/10)});
            cos.push({x: i, y: .5 * Math.cos(i/10)});
        }

        return [
            {values: sin, key: "Sine Wave", color: "#ff7f0e"},
            {values: cos, key: "Cosine Wave", color: "#2ca02c"}
        ];
    }

    function sinData() {
        var sin = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            sin.push({x: i, y: Math.sin(i/10) * Math.random() * 100});
        }

        return [{
            values: sin,
            key: "Sine Wave",
            color: "#ff7f0e"
        }];
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume your [code](http://jsbin.com/kesuyu/edit?html,js,output) is correct and it returns the correct x-axis label.

Comment: I think it is returning the index of the bar and not the corresponding x-axis label...change the value of x from x=i to x=i*13 and you will see that the index of bar is returned by i

Comment: So if clicked on a bar what output do you expect. Give a value from your example.

Comment: @SiddP I have edited the code in the question....now when i click the first bar 2 should be alerted and on progressing down the bars and on clicking the bar,you may see the difference between the alerted value and corresponding approximate x-axis value

Comment: Check the link in the first comment i sent you. Is that the output you expect.

Comment: You haven't changed anything in your code in first link....that isn't the output i am expecting ......replace this line sin.push({x: i, y: Math.sin(i/10) * Math.random() * 100}); in your code with sin.push({x: i*2, y: Math.sin(i/10) * Math.random() * 100}); and see if the output is coming correct....on clicking first bar,1 is returned,while 2 should be returned